# How to deploy ASP.NET webservice to IIS 7?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis-7, msdeploy

How can I deploy an ASP.NET web service to IIS 7?

I have deployed my webservice to IIS-5 installed on windows server 2008. However, I am not well versed with configuration options in IIS-7.

For IIS-5 I followed the below steps.

1. Create new virtual directory in IIS
2. Open the Webservice in Visual Studio
3. Go to Build
4. Publish website
5. Publish to Local IIS
6. Choose the same virtual directory created in Step-1

What are the steps for IIS-7 as these steps are not working? I am getting error 404. I have tried setting the `Default Document` to `.asmx`.

Comment: You are receiving a 404 - Not found error, which means that either you typed the url incorrectly or the service file does not exist. Your steps to deploy are correct since you are doing it from Visual Studio

Answer (score 4):

1. rebuild project in VS
2. copy project folder to iis folder, probably C:\inetpub\wwwroot\
3. in iis manager (run>inetmgr) add website, point to folder, point application pool based on your .net
4. add web service to created website, almost the same as 3.
5. INSTALL ASP 
   for windows 7 and .net 4.0:
   c:\windows\microsoft.net framework\v4.(some numbers)\regiis.exe -i
6. check access to web service on your browser